# email works on everything but Gmail app on IOS for Media Queries

Tags: ios, gmail, html-email

I have looked through countless responses about this but it just doesn't make sense as to why this will not work on the Iphones latest Gmail app. When I look on an iPhone in the Gmail app the images are not centered but in every other application, they are. In the browser on an iPhone, they are as well. This seems to only be happening for iPhones Gmail.

[image]

It works everywhere else but my media queries are not being reflected for images... Is there a certain way that you have to use the CSS in this...

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<!--<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">-->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro:wght@300;400;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<title>STARR GATE</title>
<style type="text/css">
    html {
        width: 100%;
        background: #fff;
    }
    
    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: 'ariel', sans-serif;
        background: #fff;
        font-size: 14px;
        color: #000000;
    }
    
    a {
        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: 300;
        font-style: normal;
        outline: none;
        color: #000;
    }
    
    img {
        outline: none;
    }
    
    table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    
    body {
        width: auto;
    }
    
    @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
        body {
            width: auto;
        }
        body table {
            width: 100% !important;
            max-width: 100% !important;
            display: table;
        }
        body table table {
            width: 100% !important;
            max-width: 100% !important;
            display: table;
        }

        .tablefull {
            width: 100% !important;
            max-width: 100% !important;
            display: table !important;
        }
    }
</style>

<!--[if mso]>
        <style type=”text/css”>
        body, table, td {
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        }
        </style>
    <![endif]-->

    <!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
<o:AllowPNG/>
<o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
   </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
</xml><![endif]-->

</head>

<body>
<table width="600px" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#fff" style="background-color: #fff; max-width: 600px;">
    
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" width="100%" align="left">
            <div class="img-container center autowidth"></div>
            <!-- logo -->
            <img src="https://d15k2d11r6t6rl.cloudfront.net/public/users/Integrators/BeeProAgency/509431_490051/avweb-logo.jpg" align="center" alt="" style="padding-right: 0px;padding-left: 0px;">
            </div>
            <!-- banner -->
            <table width="100%" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table width="600" align="left" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="margin:0 auto; border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; border: 0px; max-width:600px;" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                            <tr>
                                <td align="left" style="padding:0;">
                                    <table width="100%" align="left" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="margin:0 auto; border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; border: 0px; max-width:600px;">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td width="600" height="50" style="padding:0; line-height: 50px;">
                                                <img src="https://d15k2d11r6t6rl.cloudfront.net/public/users/Integrators/BeeProAgency/509431_490051/banner.png " alt="" style="width:100%;">
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <!-- cta-block -->
            <table width="100%" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #deeaf3;text-align: center; background-color: #fff;">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table width="600" align="left" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="margin:0 auto; border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; border: 0px; max-width:600px;" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                            <tr>
                                <td align="left" style="padding:0 20px;">
                                    <table width="100%" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="margin:0 auto; border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; border: 0px; max-width:484px;">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td height="40" style="padding:0; line-height: 40px;"></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td width="600" align="center" style="font-size: 16px; line-height: 24px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color:#002f5f;">
                                                Begin your pre-flight checklist long before you enter the cockpit with aircraft renters insurance. With Starr Gate, you can purchase a policy in minutes directly through the iPad app. Choose monthly or annual insurance, and pay for the coverage you need. 
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td height="20" style="padding:0; line-height: 20px;"></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td width="600" align="center">
                                                <table align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width:auto;text-align: center;">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td align="center" style="padding: 15px; background-color: #e9b659; border-radius: 50px;width: 250px;display: inline-block;text-align: center;">
                                                            <a href="https://www.starrgate.com/?utm_source=email&utm_medium=avweb&utm_campaign=button-1" target="_blank" style="line-height: normal; font-size: 13px; color: #000; font-family: 'Source Sans Pro','arial', sans-serif; display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; -webkit-border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; text-decoration: none;letter-spacing: 0.09em;text-transform: uppercase;font-weight: 700;">Buy Custom Coverage Now</a>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td height="40" style="padding:0; line-height: 40px;"></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <!-- col-50 -->
            <table width="100%" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="background-color: #fff;">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table width="600" align="left" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="margin:0 auto; border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; border: 0px; max-width:600px;" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                            <tr>
                                <td align="left">
                                    <table width="100%" align="left" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="margin:0 auto; border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; border: 0px; max-width:600px;">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <table class="tablefull" width="280" align="left" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="padding: 0;">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <table width="100%" align="left" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td width="260" height="35" style="padding:0; line-height: 35px;">
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </table>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td style="padding-left: 19px;">
                                                            <table width="100%" align="left" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="max-width: 260px;">
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td align="left" width="100%" style="font-size: 22px; line-height: 28px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color:#002f5f; font-weight: bold; text-align: left;">
                                                                        Fly Safer & Save Up to 35%
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td height="14" style="padding:0; line-height: 14px;">
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td style="font-size: 16px; line-height: 24px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color:#002f5f;">
                                                                        Save on your insurance by tracking your flight safety with CloudAhoy and improving your score. Without Starr Gate, you’re missing out on coverage discounts up to 35% off. 
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td height="20" style="padding:0; line-height: 20px;">
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td>
                                                                        <table align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width:auto; text-align:center;">
                                                                            <tr>
                                                                                <td align="center" style="padding: 14px; background-color: #e9b659; border-radius: 50px;width: 230px;display: inline-block;text-align: center;">
                                                                                    <a href="https://www.starrgate.com/?utm_source=email&utm_medium=avweb&utm_campaign=button-2" target="_blank" style="line-height: normal; font-size: 13px; color: #000; font-family: 'Source Sans Pro','arial', sans-serif; font-weight: 700; display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; -webkit-border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; text-decoration: none;letter-spacing: 0.09em;text-transform: uppercase;font-weight: 700;display: inline-block;">
                                                                                        Calculate Your Rates
                                                                                    </a>
                                                                                </td>
                                                                            </tr>
                                                                        </table>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </table>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <table width="100%" align="left" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td width="260" height="40" style="padding:0; line-height: 40px;"></td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </table>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                                <table class="tablefull" width="300" align="right" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="padding: 0;">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <table width="100%" align="left" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="max-width: 300px;">
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td width="100%" align="left">
                                                                        <img src="https://d15k2d11r6t6rl.cloudfront.net/public/users/Integrators/BeeProAgency/509431_490051/score.png" alt="" style="width:100%;margin: auto;display: block;">
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </table>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <!-- col-50 -->
            <table width="100%" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table width="600" align="left" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="margin:0 auto; border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; border: 0px; max-width:600px;" bgcolor="#002f5f">
                            <tr>
                                <td align="left">
                                    <table width="100%" align="left" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="margin:0 auto; border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; border: 0px; max-width:600px;">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <table class="tablefull" width="300" align="left" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="padding: 0;">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <table width="100%" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="max-width: 300px; text-align:center;">
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td width="100%" align="center">
                                                                        <img src="https://d15k2d11r6t6rl.cloudfront.net/public/users/Integrators/BeeProAgency/509431_490051/insurance-left-img.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%; margin: auto;display: block;">
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </table>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                                <table class="tablefull" width="280" align="left" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="padding: 0;">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <table width="100%" align="left" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td width="260" height="20" style="padding:0; line-height: 20px;">
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </table>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td style="padding:0 20px;">
                                                            <table width="100%" align="left" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="max-width: 280px;">
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td align="left" width="100%" style="font-size: 22px; line-height: 28px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color:#fff; font-weight: bold; text-align: left;">
                                                                        Get the Coverage You Need Now 
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td style="height: 15px;"></td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td style="font-size: 16px; line-height: 24px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color:#fff;">
                                                                        Starr Gate helps you find the flexible plan that works best for you. Don’t miss out on great flying weather because you’re not covered.
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td height="20" style="padding:0; line-height: 20px;">
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td>
                                                                        <table align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width:auto; text-align:center; margin-left: 0;">
                                                                            <tr>
                                                                                <td align="center" style="padding: 16px; background-color: #e9b659; border-radius: 50px;width: 190px;display: inline-block;text-align: center;">
                                                                                    <a href="https://www.starrgate.com/?utm_source=email&utm_medium=avweb&utm_campaign=button-3" target="_blank" style="line-height: normal; font-size: 13px; color: #000; font-family: 'Source Sans Pro','arial', sans-serif; font-weight: 700; display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; -webkit-border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; text-decoration: none;letter-spacing: 0.09em;text-transform: uppercase;font-weight: 700;display: inline-block;">
                                                                                        Complete Your Purchase
                                                                                    </a>
                                                                                </td>
                                                                            </tr>
                                                                        </table>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </table>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <table width="100%" align="left" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td width="260" height="20" style="padding:0; line-height: 20px;">
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </table>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            
            <!-- disclaimer-block -->
            <table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #deeaf3;text-align: center;">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table width="600" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="margin:0 auto; border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; border: 0px; max-width:600px;" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" style="padding:0 20px;">
                                    <table width="100%" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="margin:0 auto; border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; border: 0px; max-width:484px;">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td height="25" style="padding:0; line-height: 25px;"></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td width="600" align="center" style="font-size: 12px; line-height: 18px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color:#002f5f;">
                                                This is only a brief description of the coverage(s) available. The policy will contain reductions, limitations, exclusions, and termination provisions. Policies are underwritten by Starr Indemnity & Liability Company.
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td height="25" style="padding:0; line-height: 25px;"></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <!-- footer -->
            <hr style="border: 1px solid #000000;">
            <center><a style="color:#000000;font-weight:bold;"href="https://www.avweb.com/?MailingID=%CAMPAIGNID%&st=pmail&sc=Footer">www.avweb.com</a></center>
            <center><p>Sent to: %EMAIL%</p></center>
            <center><p><a href="https://www.avweb.com/privacy">Privacy Policy</a> | <a href="https://www.avweb.com/privacy#CALIFORNIA-RESIDENTS">Do Not Sell My Personal Information</a> | <a href="%UNSUBSCRIBELINK%">Unsubscribe</a></p></center>
            <center><p>%SENDER-INFO-SINGLELINE%</p></center>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The image is messy but it's not clear which part of it is wrong according to your requirements; could you please [edit] to explain in more detail what you expect?

Comment: @tripleee I updated the description. Basically, I am trying to get it where in gmail on iphone it has a width of 100%. It has that in outlook and the web but not this application and I feel like I am just spinning myself in circles.

Comment: Gmail has the tendency to ignore code that it "thinks" is wrong. This might work (or not) but can you try removing the space before 480px in your media query and try? Make it `max-width:480px`.

Answer (score 0):

Really simple solution to this, you've got a really old technique for your CSS selector.
Convert: table[class="tablefull"]
to .tablefull

Further to that, I've noticed a lot of extra code you don't really need. Doesn't look like these extra attributes and properties are causing any obvious issues but if this template were to grow by 3 or 4 times, that bloat will make or break your efforts to avoid clipping in Gmail.

The extra code I'm specifically pinpointing is:

- align attributes on 100% width tables
- different align attribute values on elements with margin:0 auto (which is for centring)
- widths on table cells when there is only one table cell
- padding:0 on tables which don't have padding on them
- There is also a weird issue with the doctype being commented out and the order of the initial elements that could cause issues.

There are a bunch more but just food for thought.

Comment: I updated the post with that to make sure I had it right. I changed it and tried to send but I am still getting the same results.

Comment: This is essentially right--there might be one or two more styles in the `<style>` block that Gmail iOS doesn't like. It then promptly deletes the entire block! Remove duplicates, and body table table.